# press "_" or ":" with pyautgui (python3)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to press "_" or ":" characters with a pyautogui script.

if i try in a console i get this:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.press(':')
>>> /
>>> pyautogui.hotkey('shift', ':')
>>> /
>>> pyautogui.press('_')
>>> 8
>>> pyautogui.hotkey('shift', '_')
>>> 8
```

The problem is the same with other special characters.

I don't know if it's important but I have a french keyboard.

how do I get these characters ?

Comment: To type characters rather then keys use `write()` instead of press. It supports capital letters and special characters.

Comment: pyautogui doesn't support AZERTY keyboards as of the time I write this. There's an issue tracking this, https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/137. You might be able to find a workaround by reading through that thread.

Comment: Thank you Carter Shanklin. I think it's actually the keyboard that's the problem... I'm going to look for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in an IDE. It's probably because you're running this from the shell. Try it on sublime or pycharm.

Edit: Sublime worked fine for me

Comment: No, i use python console of Pycharm. I have the same problem with scripts (written in Pycharm).